# Nested function pointer declarations

Tags: c

I found this declaration in the APUE book in the chapter on signals:

```
void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

I don't fully understand the syntax.  The declaration of (*func) is syntactically what I expect for a function parameter/pointer.  I don't understand the syntax where "signal" is declared, and the trailing (int).  I was wondering if someone could clarify this.  -Thanks

Comment: `cdecl` can help you. Unfortunately finding the correct way to feed the type into `cdecl` is tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `signal` returns a pointer to a function of type `void (int)`, and has two arguments: an `int` and a pointer to a function of type `void (int)`.

So something like this should work

```c
void foo(int);

void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int)
{
    return func;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(42, foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spiral rule (reading inside out clockwise) to understand the syntax:

1. Find the identifier

   ```
    void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
           ^    ^
           |    |
           +----+
             |
          Identifier name
   ```

`signal` is a ....

2. Move right

   ```
    void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
                 ^                            ^
                 |                            |
                 +----------------------------+
                                |
                            arguments (so, its a function)
   ```

`signal` is a function which accepts `int` and `void (*) (int)` *[pointer to a function which accepts a `int` argument and returns nothing (`void`)]* as arguments ....

3. Can't move right anymore because of the right parenthesis, so move left.

   ```
    void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
          ^
          |
       pointer
   ```

`signal` is a function which accepts `int` and `void (*) (int)` as arguments and returns a pointer ....

4. Can't move left anymore because of the left parenthesis, so keep going right.

   ```
    void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
                                                ^   ^
                                                |   |
                                                +---+
                                                  |
                                               argument 
                      (which means signal() is returning a function pointer)
   ```

`signal` is a function which accepts `int` and `void (*) (int)` as arguments and returns a pointer to a function which accepts a `int` argument and ....

5. Can't move right anymore because we're out of symbols, so go left.

   ```
    void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int)))(int);
    ^  ^
    |  |
    +--+
      |
    return type of function whose pointer returned by signal() function
   ```

`signal` is a function which accepts `int` and `void (*) (int)` as arguments and returns a pointer to function which accepts a `int`  argument and returns nothing (`void`).